# Installed Tomcat 8 with JAMWiki on Windows XP, Now Getting Parsing Error

Tags: apache, parsing, tomcat

I have no Java experience, so this issue is eluding me completely.

I'm setting up an internal wiki (JAMWiki) because we need 100% MediaWiki syntax compatibility.

I installed JavaRE 7 (1.7.0_40-b43), Tomcat 8.0.0/RC1, and JAMWiki (1.3.2) on Windows XP (SP2). Installation and setup went well until I attempted to visit the home page of the wiki.

I keep receiving 2 errors when going to the home page of JAMWiki. The errors seem to randomly alternate between the two.

Here are the error messages:

Error #1

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/category-include.jsp
>   (line: 31, column: 3) "${(numSubCategories > 9) && (columnCount < 3)
>   && ((status.count * 3) >= (numSubCategories * columnCount))}" contains
>   invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the
>   expression [${(numSubCategories > 9) && (columnCount < 3) &&
>   ((status.count * 3) >= (numSubCategories * columnCount))}]

Error #2

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.topic_jsp /
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.topic_jsp

I then installed the previous version of JAMWiki (1.3.1) just to see if it was an bug with the newest version, but the two errors keep appearing identically.

Any ideas what the next step would be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure Tomcat can use a JRE? I always thought that Tomcat needs a JDK (because of the compiler)?

Comment: "100% MediaWiki syntax compatibility" sounds chimerical, there isn't even a specification for wikitext. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled Apache Tomcat 8 RC1 and installed Tomcat 7.0.42, then installed JAMWiki 1.3.2 (the latest version).

The error is gone and the wiki is working fine.